# Configuring cups to accept multiple jobs from Mac end users

Tags: printing, cups

I have a CUPS server up and running with a print release station working fine. I'm not just trying to fine tune it. Right now my mac end users have their print jobs stack up in their local queue, and they can release them one at a time from the station. The only trouble is that the jobs only show up one at a time, meaning if a user has submitted 5 jobs to the print release station, only the first job will appear.

Any way to store jobs on the CUPS server for later processing after the user touches the "release job" button?